# Error: pip install pycapnp

Tags: python, pip, capnproto

I've been trying to install pycapnp via pip on my macbook pro. But I seem to be having issues trying to download it.

The following is the error:

```
warning: "Your compiler supports C++11 but your C++ standard library does not.  
If your "               "system has libc++ installed (as should be the case 
on e.g. Mac OSX), try adding "               "-stdlib=libc++ to your CXXFLAGS." 
[-W#warnings]
      #warning "Your compiler supports C++11 but your C++ standard library does not.
  If your "\
       ^
/private/var/folders/yv/f6fy_dm51799h6htr1nd30480000gn/T/pip-build-doQpew/
pycapnp/build/include/kj/common.h:78:10: fatal error: 'initializer_list' file 
not found
#include <initializer_list>
         ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/
private/var/folders/yv/f6fy_dm51799h6htr1nd30480000gn/T/pip-build-doQpew/pycapnp/
setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=
f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
 install --record /var/folders/yv/f6fy_dm51799h6htr1nd30480000gn/T/
pip-hawqg0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yv/f6fy_dm51799h6htr1nd30480000gn/
T/pip-build-doQpew/pycapnp/
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try installing inside of virtualenv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to installed it by declaring

```
➜ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
```

Or

```
➜ CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' pip install pycapnp
```

Or

```
➜ export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
➜ export CFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
```

You can see more details from [this issue](https://github.com/jparyani/pycapnp/issues/63)

---

By the way, I installed it successfully in virtualenv on my Macbook.

Comment: Thank you so much @McGrady! It worked! I tried -

    `export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
    export CFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got a new error after running the installation command by adding "CFLAGS". To resolve that error I had to install `Cmake` and `protobuf` by using the following command: `brew install Cmake` and `brew install protobuf`..